# What's the difference between HTML5 canvas and standard DIVS

Tags: html, html5-canvas

Does  have additional or less functionality than using standard divs.

I am just learning HTML5 and can't understand the difference between  and , other than semantics.

Comment: Html5 Canvas is an artbook with a pencil. A Div is the desk you put the Canvas on to.

Comment: That's where I am confused. I understand the difference conceptually, but I don't understand the difference functionally. Other than semantics and structure, can the canvas element do anything or take any properties that a div can't?

Comment: Yes, Html Canvas is a powerful drawing surface. Think of Canvas as a cut-down version of Photoshop. It has properties & methods allowing you to use to draw lines, curves, images, text on that canvas.  Canvas allows styling such as fill color, stroke color, opacity, etc, etc. Canvas allows transformations like rotations & scaling. Canvas supports advanced processes like compositing and pixel manipulation.  All drawings on canvas are ordered from JavaScript using drawing commands, **so if you just put a canvas on the page it will begin as a blank canvas before you draw with javascript.**

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. This makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

`<canvas>` is an element semantically dedicated for drawing graphics dynamically via scripting.

`<div>` is a general-purpose container.

Comment: But in theory, I can use a div instead of a canvas and achieve the same output?

Comment: Not quite. A `canvas` element is of type [`HTMLCanvasElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement) when used in scripting, and has methods for drawing/rendering (e.g. `getContext()`). A regular `div` doesn't have this. But you can of course dynamically create a canvas inside a div by a JS script...

Answer (score 0):

The HTML  element is used to draw graphics, on the fly, via JavaScript.

The  element is only a container for graphics. You must use JavaScript to actually draw the graphics.

Canvas has several methods for drawing paths, boxes, circles, text, and adding images.

---

A  section in a document that is styled with CSS:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).